# Check if a cell contains any of words from a dynamic list

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I want to use a formula to populate the "RESULTS" cells. I need it to check if the adjacent "CHECKED CELL" contains any of the words listed in the "KEYWORDS" cells.

Ideally, I would be able to add new words to the Keywords list at will. So, I've been trying to make the range something like "$A$2:$A".

Example - [C2]: "Does [B2] contain any of the words in {$A$2:$A}"?

I have not been able to find a way to accomplish this with a formula. Any ideas?

---

**[A1] KEYWORDS**

[A2] dog

[A3] squirrel

[A4] moose

[A5] cat

---

**[B1] CHECKED CELL**

[B2] alkj moose adfli

[B3] AMSCRAM

[B4] 124 liML

[B5] dog LImfo

---

**[C1] RESULTS**

[C2] yes

[C3] no

[C4] no

[C5] yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an array formula. For a fixed range, the formula in `C2` would be

```
=IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH($A$2:$A$5,$B2),0))>0,"yes","no")
```

Be sure to enter this as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll know it worked when you get curly brackets { } on either end of the formula.

If you want the range to be dynamic, one good way is to define a named range. If you try to use all of column `A:A` then everything will return `yes` because both the `SEARCH` and `FIND` functions return `TRUE` if the string you're looking for is blank. Since `A:A` would contain blanks under your list, all your results will be `yes` and that's not helpful. Instead, we need to define a dynamic named range. There are a few ways to do this but I like to open the "Name Manager" (It's in the middle of the "Formulas" ribbon in the "Defined Names" section).  Open that and click "New" in the top left. Give it a name like `Keywords` and a "Refers to" formula

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A:$A),0,0),0)-2)
```

[image: Screenshot]

Now you can change the formula in `C1` to be this (still entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)

```
=IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(Keywords,$B2),0))>0,"yes","no")
```

---

**Caveat #1**

`SEARCH` is case-insensitive. If you want a case-sensitive search, replace it with `FIND`.

---

**Caveat #2**

The formula for the dynamic named range assumes that there aren't any blanks in the keywords list. It will reference all the cells from `A2` until the cell before the first blank. Of course, this also assumes that there is a blank *somewhere* in `A:A` which means that your keywords list has to be less than 1,048,575 items long.

---

**Caveate #3**

You can do this without the named range but your formula gets long and harder to follow. However, it does keep it all packaged into a single formula. If your data is very large, I would recommend the named range as it'll speed up calculations. To combine it all, the formula in `C2` would be

```
=IF(MAX(IFERROR(SEARCH(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,1,0,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A:$A),0,0),0)-2),$B2),0))>0,"yes","no")
```

Comment: This seems to be working just right. Awesome I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small *User Defined Function* (UDF):

```
Public Function MultiMatch(sIN As String, rng As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range
    MultiMatch = "no"

    For Each r In rng
        If InStr(1, sIN, r.Text) > 0 Then
            MultiMatch = "yes"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=MultiMatch(B1,$A$1:$A$4)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

[image]

Comment: @fixer1234  Thank you ....................I will take a look..........

Comment: @fixer1234  In you linked question, we don't need VBA, only a fuzzy match and an index.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I was looking to avoid using VB.