# Find if a cell contains a word from a list, including words that might be mispelled

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-365

My question is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/904164/check-if-a-cell-contains-any-of-words-from-a-dynamic-list) posted previously. My data is organized in the following manner:

- Column A (Outcome) - contains user entered text describing an outcome. This can be of varying lengths.

Example: On March 2, we found a green scarf with fringes. No one came forward to claim this scarf so we left it in the bin for 10 days. After 10 days, it was donated to a shlter.

- Column D (search terms) - contains a list of words to look for in the Outcome column.

Example:  scarf, mitten, hat, shelter

- Column B (Match) - checks to see if a word/words from Column D are within the outcome text. This is a true/false field. I'm using this formula:

  =XLOOKUP(TRUE,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D:D,A2))),D:D,"false")

Example: This would be True because it contains "scarf".

**My question is this:** In the above example, "shelter" appears as a search term in Column D. You'll notice that the word "shelter" is spelled wrong in Column A. If "scarf" was not in the list as well, Column C would have returned "False". Is there a way that Excel can also identify similar spelling so that "shlter" would have been recognized as "shelter" and therefore marked as "True"?

I've tried using the Fuzzy Lookup add-on but it just returns 0. I suspect this is because Column A contains such a long string that any matches it does find just get reduced to 0.

I'm using Microsoft365, but I recognize this problem might beyond Excel so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, Excel natively will not be able to distinguish that `shlter` is equivalent to `shelter`.  You would need to create a table of all misspellings and there correct word to compare.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for the comment. I figured it was a long shot, so thank you for confirming this.

Comment: I haven't tried, but for your use case maybe the "Fuzzy Lookup Add-In for Excel" from Microsoft

Comment: If it is an option for you, you may be able to do this using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365. You might have to put your list of key words elsewhere, though. But there is a fuzzy matching algorithm, and you can adjust the sensitivity.